Search interactive report for values appearing in sql on other page
So I am making a interactive report (IR) on a page (lets say page 2) that shows a certain set of values from different tables. Each row has a unique number and when you click on that number it opens a modal page (page 3) with a new report from a new query. I was wondering if it is possible to search on page 2 for values in page 3. So for instance i am a looking for a specific number that  is available on page 3 (because otherwise the query of page 2 would get too cluttered), its corresponding unique number would show up on the IR in page 2, then i click on the number to open up the modal page where the value appears that I was looking for.
I hope my question is undertandable.
Thanks in advance for your help.

I don't understand what you mean. Can you describe it with an actual business example ?

It is a bit confusing, sorry but I'm not sure what it is all about. If pg 3 is modal with IR containing some specific number you would like to have on pg2 then:
you can create a PopupLOV or a Selection list on pg 2 (based on a reduced query from pg 3 with the data of interest ) for user to choose from.
If you want a specific value from IR on pg 3 to be shown on pg 2 (by clicking on a certain row of the pg 3 IR) then make your IR to be IG (for if the report is static and you don't want any interaction on it, then use Report):
Create a field to hold the value on pg 2:
P2_YOUR_FIELD
Under pg 3 IR

Synchronize Columns
Get an index (starting with 0) of a column of interest (1st col index = 0; 2nd col index = 1; ....)

Under pg 3 IR
Create dynamic action with properties:
Identification:
Name: SelectionChg
Execution:
Event Scope: Static
Type: Immediate
When:
Event: Selection Change [Interactive Grid]
Selection Type:  Region
Region:  YOUR_IR_REGION
Client-side Condition:
Type: JavaScript expression
JavaScript Expression: this.data.SelectedRecords[0] != undefined
Create True action with properties:
Identification:
Name: RecChanged
Action: Execute JavaScript Code
Settings:
Code:
var value = this.data.selectedRecords[0][0];
apex.item( "P2_YOUR_FIELD" ).setValue (value);
/* last [0] is index of pg 3 IR's column   */
Create another True action with properties:
Identification:
Name: SetVal
Action: SetValue
Settings:
Set Type: PL/SQL Expression
PL/SQL Expression: :P2_YOUR_FIELD
Items to Submit:  P2_YOUR_FIELD
Affected Elements:
Selection Type: Item(s)
Item(s): P2_YOUR_FIELD
Click on any row on pg 3 IR should transfer the column[index] value to pg 2 field P2_YOUR_FIELD...
